# Delphi-7 packed records to C# structs

Tags: c#, delphi, struct, delphi-7, record

I'm in the process of converting a Delphi program to C#. I was told to basically go line by line and convert. Having never used Delphi before, I was wondering if my conversion of packed records to C# structs are correct?

Delphi:

```
Type

  RPrec = packed record
     now: TDateTime;
     ShipLatitude: longint;
     ShipLatUncertainty: short;
     ShipAltitude: single;
     FishLatitude: longint;
     FishHeading: single;
     ContactID: longint;
     Range1: short;
    end;


    RPhdrec = packed record
     now: TDateTime;
     MinimumLatitude: longint;
     MinimumAltitude: single;
    end;

    Vehiclerec = packed record
       Latitude: longint;
       LonUncertainty: short;
       Altitude: single;
     end;

   VehiclerecPtr =  ^Vehiclerec; 

   RAMPrec2 = packed record
         now: TDateTime;
         Ship:Vehiclerec;
         DataAvailFlags: longint;
         Range2: short;
    end;
```

C#

```
        public struct RPrec
        {
            DateTime now;
            int ShipLatitude;
            short ShipLatUncertainty;
            float ShipAltitude;
            int FishLatitude;
            float FishHeading;
            short Range1;
        }

        public struct RPhdrec
        {
            DateTime now;
            int MinimumLatitude;
            float MinimumAltitude;
        }

        public struct Vehiclerec
        {
            int Latitude;
            short LonUncertainty;
            float Altitude;
        }

        public struct RAMPrec2
        {
            DateTime now;
            Vehiclerec Ship;
            int DataAvailFlags;
            short Range2;
        }
```

Does this seem okay? I've seen examples of people using StructLayouts which I've never used before, would that be better?

Comment: Delphi `TDateTime` is not an *exact* copy of C# `DateTime`

Comment: Oh you are right! I was looking at http://netcoole.com/delphi2cs/datatype.htm, but found this info: "`NT or OLE DateTime data type is identical to a double floating point type. `"

Comment: Would I just do something like this?
  `double dbl = 65985.3333;
   DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dbl)`

Comment: It depends on what do you expect from conversion. If you want to have *interoperability*, you have to change `DateTime` to `double`, add `StructLayout` in order to pack the struct etc. However if all you need is to implement a C# program based on inherited Delphi algorithm, you'd rather change `struct` into `class`, change *fields* to *properties* etc.

Comment: Basically the data I get will either already be in the Delphi format or the .net DateTime, but it will always be displayed in the Delphi format, and needs to be editable like .addSeconds, minutes, etc.

Comment: As far as can see, all you need is to implement a *serialization/deserialization* to and from the given format; so do not copy Delphi *records* into `struct`s, but implement convenient C# classes.